# How do i avoid starting dd over again after a system freeze?

Tags: freeze, dd

Some days ago I decided to wipe my 750 GB hard disk in order to sell it, so I booted `Ubuntu` off a live DVD and started the process with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`. I left `dd` running during the night. When I came back in the morning I discovered that at some point of the process `Ubuntu` freezed. I'm unable to determine at which point of the process the freeze happened, because whenever it happened it happened while the screen saver was on, so i wasn't able see `bash`'s output.

Question: How do I avoid starting dd over again?

Comment: You can shred it. run `man shred`

Comment: @Mudit I need to start from the the point where the freeze occured, not to wipe the whole drive again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked out a solution myself:

**Quick answer**

Assuming that your drive is `/dev/sdX`:

- Run `dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - /dev/sdX` to spot the first non-zero byte of the device: in my case it was byte `742300476649`
- Calculate to which block does the first non-zero byte belong to: `<device_first_non_zero_block>=floor(<device_first_non_zero_byte>/<device_block_size>)+1`: you can check your `<device_block_size>` running `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` in a terminal: in my case it was block `1449805619`
- Start `dd` again from there: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=<device_block_size> skip=<device_first_non_zero_block>-1`: in my case the command was `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 skip=1449805618`

**Long answer**

Giving `cmp` `-` as `FILE1` will force it to read `FILE1` from `stdin`, so a constant stream of zeros will make `cmp` compare each byte of `FILE2` against zero until `EOF`, reporting (if any) the first non-zero byte: assuming that the drive is `/dev/sdX`:

`dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - /dev/sdX`

The first non-zero block of the device is the block containing the first non-zero byte, i.e.:

```
<device_first_non_zero_block>=floor(<device_first_non_zero_byte>/<device_block_size>)+1
```

So, to start `dd` again from there, just skip the first `<device_first_non_zero_block>-1` blocks:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=<device_block_size> skip=<device_first_non_zero_block>-1
```

**Testing**

Creating a 512KB file containing only zeros to simulate a wiped hard drive:

`$ dd if=/dev/zero of=hdd1 bs=512 count=1000`

Creating a 512KB file containing only random bytes to simulate a hard drive containing data:

`$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=hdd2 bs=512 count=1000`

Merging the two files to simulate a partially wiped hard drive:

`$ cat hdd1 hdd2 > hdd3`

Output of the command on the test drives:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - hdd1
cmp: EOF on hdd1
# cmp reached EOF on hdd1, hdd1 contains only zeros
$ dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - hdd2
- hdd2 differ: byte 1, line 1
# cmp reported byte 1 to be not zero, hdd2 doesn't contain any leading zero
$ dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - hdd3
- hdd3 differ: byte 512001, line 1
# cmp reported byte 512001 to be not zero, hdd3 contains leading zeros up to byte 512000
```

In this case:

```
<device_first_non_zero_block>=floor(512001/512)+1=floor(1000,001953125)+1=1000+1=1001
```

So, to start `dd` again from there:

> notice that in this case, being the test drive a file, `count` is needed and has been set to `<device_total_number_of_blocks>-(<device_first_non_zero_block>-1)` in order to not exceed the test drive size, but this doesn't apply to regular drives

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=hdd3 bs=512 seek=1000 count=1000
```

Output of the command on `hdd3`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test2 bs=512 seek=1000 count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
512000 bytes (512 kB) copied, 0,00190399 s, 269 MB/s
```

Checking if the procedure succeded:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero | cmp - hdd3
cmp: EOF on hdd3
```

Bingo!

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)